# how to retrive array of objects based on object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, arrayobject

How to get array of objects based on object and arraylist using javascript

return the array of objects based on two conditions

1.if `arrobj value is equal to obj valueid`
and  `cid value should not include only listcode` value

2.else if  `arrobj value is equal to obj valueid` and `codevalue is equal to cid`

else return []

should follow above conditions and return arrayobject using javscript

```
var listcode =["IN","FI", "FR"];
var arrobj =[
  {id:1, name: "jan", cid: "IN", value: "1234"},
  {id:2, name: "feb", cid: "SG", value: "2468"},
  {id:3, name: "mar", cid: "SP", value: "2468"},
  {id:4, name: "apri", cid: "FI", value: "2345"},
]
var obj={
  id:5, name: "zen", codevalue: "SP", valueid:"2468"
}

Expected Output
[
  {id:2, name: "feb", cid: "SG", value: "2468"},
  {id:3, name: "mar", cid: "SP", value: "2468"},
]

var listcode =["IN","FI","FR"];
var arrobj1 =[
  {id:1, name: "jan", cid: "IN", value: "1234"},
  {id:2, name: "feb", cid: "FI", value: "2468"},
  {id:3, name: "mar", cid: "IN", value: "2468"},
  {id:4, name: "apri", cid: "FI", value: "2345"},
]
var obj1={
  id:5, name: "zen", codevalue: "SP", valueid:"2468"
}
Expected Output
[]

const result = arrobj.filter(e => e.value === obj.valueid
      && listcode.includes(e.cid));
``
```

Comment: please write a better question in order to understand what's happening here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything right, just add a negation before `!includes`

```js
// data1
var listcode1 = ["IN","FI", "FR"];
var arrobj1 = [
  {id:1, name: "jan", cid: "IN", value: "1234"},
  {id:2, name: "feb", cid: "SG", value: "2468"},
  {id:3, name: "mar", cid: "SP", value: "2468"},
  {id:4, name: "apri", cid: "FI", value: "2345"},
]
var obj1 = { id:5, name: "zen", codevalue: "SP", valueid:"2468"}


// data2
var listcode2 = ["IN","FI","FR"];
var arrobj2 = [
  {id:1, name: "jan", cid: "IN", value: "1234"},
  {id:2, name: "feb", cid: "FI", value: "2468"},
  {id:3, name: "mar", cid: "IN", value: "2468"},
  {id:4, name: "apri", cid: "FI", value: "2345"},
]
var obj2 = { id:5, name: "zen", codevalue: "SP", valueid:"2468"}

function getNewArray(inputList, obj, listCodes) {
  const result = inputList.filter(x => x.value === obj.valueid && (!listCodes.includes(x.cid) || x.cid === obj.codevalue))
  return result;
}


console.log(getNewArray(arrobj1, obj1, listcode1))
console.log(getNewArray(arrobj2, obj2, listcode2))
```

Comment: thanks a lot but one condition not working, `var listcode =["IN","FI","FR"];
var arrobj1 =[
  {id:1, name: "jan", cid: "IN", value: "1234"},
  {id:2, name: "feb", cid: "FI", value: "2468"},
  {id:3, name: "mar", cid: "IN", value: "2468"},
  {id:4, name: "apri", cid: "FI", value: "2345"},
]
var obj1={
  id:5, name: "zen", codevalue: "FI", valueid:"2468"
} 
`. arrobj value and obj valueid , codevalue and cid same should return array of objects, condition2 in my problem state

Comment: which one, please specify it better

Comment: I have added in this link -> https://jsfiddle.net/miyavv/tz7nyf2b/4/

Comment: @code123 try it now

Answer (score 2):

Is possible to achieve that by filtering the `arrobj`.

```
var listcode =["IN","FI", "FR"];
var arrobj =[
  {id:1, name: "jan", cid: "IN", value: "1234"},
  {id:2, name: "feb", cid: "SG", value: "2468"},
  {id:3, name: "mar", cid: "SP", value: "2468"},
  {id:4, name: "apri", cid: "FI", value: "2345"},
]
var obj={
  id:5, name: "zen", codevalue: "SP", valueid:"2468"
}

const result = arrobj.filter((item) => {
  return item.value === obj.valueid &&
    (
      !listcode.includes(item.cid)
      || item.cid === obj.codevalue
    )
})
```